# I can't modify a variable in a function so when it return to the main the condition of while is never satisfied

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

Basically i want the variable 'End' to control the while loop. In the while loop there is a function called to check multiple things (Is the game tic tac toe) when the function see a tris or the table full (tie) it should change the variable 'End' to -1 if someone wins or -2 if is a draw so the game should end. (This doesn't happen)

```
                printf("TURN %u\n", COUNT);      //conta turno (inglese)

                printf("Player %d:\n", Start_Num);      //giocata player1
                printf("ROW: ");
                scanf("%u", &ROW);
                    if (ROW > 2){
                        puts("ENTER A VALID VALUE (BETWEEN 0 AND 2)");  //decisione mossa
                        scanf("%u", &ROW);
                    }
                printf("COLUMN: ");
                scanf("%u", &COLUMN);
                    if (COLUMN > 2){
                        puts("ENTER A VALID VALUE (BETWEEN 0 AND 2)");
                        scanf("%u", &COLUMN);
                    }
                    if (Start_Num == 1){                    //assegnazione mossa all'array
                        TABLE[ROW][COLUMN] = P1_SIGN;
                         }
                    else {  
                        TABLE[ROW][COLUMN] = P2_SIGN;
                    }

                Print_Table_Full(TABLE);        //funzioni
                Verify_Win_Or_Tie(TABLE, P1_SIGN, P2_SIGN, End, Counter_Obj);
                


                    COUNT++;
            }
```

The while loop is incomplete but it should work anyway

```
    if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN){   //prima riga
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");  
                End = -1;                                //valore di vincita
    }
    if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[0][2] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

     if(TABLE[1][0] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[1][2] == P1_SIGN){   //seconda riga
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");   
                End = -1; 
    }
    if(TABLE[1][0] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[1][2] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

     if(TABLE[2][0] && TABLE[2][1] && TABLE[2][2] == P1_SIGN){   //terza riga
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");
                End = -1;    
    }
    if(TABLE[2][0] && TABLE[2][1] && TABLE[2][2] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

    if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[1][0] && TABLE[2][0] == P1_SIGN){   //prima colonna
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");  
                End = -1; 
    }
    if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[1][0] && TABLE[2][0] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

     if(TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[2][1] == P1_SIGN){   //seconda colonna
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");  
                End = -1;  
    }
    if(TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[2][1] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

     if(TABLE[0][2] && TABLE[1][2] && TABLE[2][2] == P1_SIGN){   //terza colonna
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n"); 
                End = -1;
    }
    if(TABLE[0][2] && TABLE[1][2] && TABLE[2][2] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }


    if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[2][2] == P1_SIGN){    //diagonale 1 
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

    if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[2][2] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

    if(TABLE[0][2] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[2][0] == P1_SIGN){    //diagonale 2
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }

    if(TABLE[0][2] && TABLE[1][1] && TABLE[2][0] == P2_SIGN){
                puts("PLAYER 2 WINS\n");
                End = -1;
    }
    
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                if(TABLE[i][j] == 'X' || TABLE[i][j] == 'O'){
                       Counter_Obj++;
                }   
               
            }
        }
        
        if (Counter_Obj == 9){
            puts("DRAW!");
            End = -2;
        }

return End;  
}
```

I even tried to use pointers. The variable End was

```
int End = 0;
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By the way, conditions like `TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN` looks weird. Do you mean `TABLE[0][0] == P1_SIGN && TABLE[0][1] == P1_SIGN && TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN`?

Comment: Can you post the complete function code? How you define the prototype (input parameters ecc.). I suppose it's `Verify_Win_Or_Tie`

Comment: ```int Verify_Win_Or_Tie(char TABLE[][T], char P1_SIGN, char P2_SIGN, int End, unsigned int Counter_Obj);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone already pointed out in the comments, I'm not sure if your `if` conditions are doing what you think they're doing.

```
if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN){   //prima riga
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");  
                End = -1;                                //valore di vincita
}
```

At the moment this piece of code, for example, is checking if `TABLE[0][0]` and `TABLE[0][1]` are (EDIT:) `!=0` and if `TABLE[0][2]` is equal to `P1_SIGN`. If this is how it supposed to work it's fine, either way you should change all your `if` like suggested in the comments (by @MikeCAT).

Another important thing is how you're using your function. You're returning a value (`End`) but not storing it anywhere, so you should do:

```
int result = Verify_Win_Or_Tie(TABLE, P1_SIGN, P2_SIGN, End, Counter_Obj);
```

Or, if you prefer to use pointers:

```
/* function now returns void */
void Verify_Win_Or_Tie(char TABLE[][T], char P1_SIGN, char P2_SIGN, int* End, unsigned int Counter_Obj) // now End is a pointer to int
{
    if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN){   //prima riga
                puts("PLAYER 1 WINS\n");  
                // updating pointed value
                *End = -1;                                //valore di vincita
    }

    /* rest of code */
}
```

How to use it on main:

```
Verify_Win_Or_Tie(TABLE, P1_SIGN, P2_SIGN, &End, Counter_Obj); // passing address of End
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In you code you should change the if condition: 
`if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN)` to 
`if((TABLE[0][0] == P1_SIGN) && (TABLE[0][1] == P1_SIGN) && (TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN))` 
 
Because `if(TABLE[0][0] && TABLE[0][1] && TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN)` is evaluted as 
`(TABLE[0][0] != 0) && (TABLE[0][1] != 0)  && (TABLE[0][2] == P1_SIGN)`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the conditione in the while loop was wrong!

```
while(Result != -1) {      //inizio gioco //condizione di vittoria o pareggio

                printf("TURN %u\n", COUNT);      //conta turno (inglese)

                printf("Player %d:\n", Start_Num);      //giocata player1
                printf("ROW: ");
                scanf("%u", &ROW);
                    if (ROW > 2){
                        puts("ENTER A VALID VALUE (BETWEEN 0 AND 2)");  //decisione mossa
                        scanf("%u", &ROW);
                    }
                printf("COLUMN: ");
                scanf("%u", &COLUMN);
                    if (COLUMN > 2){
                        puts("ENTER A VALID VALUE (BETWEEN 0 AND 2)");
                        scanf("%u", &COLUMN);
                    }
                    if (Start_Num == 1){                    //assegnazione mossa all'array
                        TABLE[ROW][COLUMN] = P1_SIGN;
                         }
                    else {  
                        TABLE[ROW][COLUMN] = P2_SIGN;
                    }

                Print_Table_Full(TABLE);        //funzioni
                Result = Verify_Win_Or_Tie(TABLE, P1_SIGN, P2_SIGN, End, Counter_Obj);
                


                    COUNT++;
            }
```

Before the while  condition was:

```
while (Result != -1 || Result != -2)
```

Resulting in an infinite loop but i still don't know why!

Comment: Because you're using an `OR (||)` in the while condition. So if result is `-1` you'll never exit because condition `Result!=-2` is still true, and viceversa. If you want to exit the moment you have a winner or a tie you should use `while (Result!=-1 && Result!=-2)`.